# Port is taken for a ssh session

Tags: postgresql, ssh

```
bind [127.0.0.1]:5432: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 5432
Could not request local forwarding.
```

I am trying to access a remote server but the port 5432 is taken.

I tried `lsof -ti:5432` but nothing is working. Plz help.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to access a remote PostgreSQL database and my question is how to unbind whatever I have on port 5432.

Comment: What `ssh` command are you running? Where are you running your `lsof` command: locally or on the remote host?

Comment: So, you have a server running postgresql. You are on your machine (client). You want to connect to the server. From your machine, type `telnet 1.1.1.1 5432`. Change 1.1.1.1 to the IP of remote computer. If you drop to a `telnet>` shell, type q. That's a good thing. That means, you client can talk to port 5432 on remote server. Are you able to telnet to that port?

Comment: okay, I was instructed to set up the connection `ssh -L localhost:5432:localhost:5432 -Y ambisense@scifilab.dyndns.org` this way. I don't know the target IP address. Any thoughts?

Comment: scifilab.dyndns.org is the remote. Try `telnet scifilab.dyndns.org 5432`.

Comment: okay, I tried your method, and received a timeout. `telnet: connect to address 192.168.1.184: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host`

Comment: got the same result

Comment: @zedfoxus I run `sudo lsof -i :5432` and see two Postgres occupying the port and it seems to me that I can't kill it. Wired

Comment: Try `sudo service postgres<tab> stop`. When you press tab after postgres, your system should ideally auto-populate the service name such as postgresql or postgresql.server or  whatever service it is. I assume you are running Ubuntu?

Comment: @zedfoxus I am running a macOS, is there a difference between `brew services stop postgresql` and `sudo service postgres<tab> stop`? Bc sudo service doesn't work for me

Comment: Yeah, `brew services stop postgresql` will work on OSX.

Comment: okay, I stopped the services but when I run `sudo lsof -i :5432`, Postgres is still running

Comment: Okay, no worries. Try this instead: `ssh -L 55432:localhost:5432 -Y ambisense@scifilab.dyndns.org`. Once you are logged in to ssh and have a tunnel, try `psql -U youruser -p 55432 -d your database`. That'll tunnel 5432 to your local computer's 55432 port.

Comment: OMG. I solved it!!!! I love StackOverflow. Such a loving community. Thank you so much!!!!!

Comment: Awesome. Did port forwarding to 55432 work for you? If so, I will put an answer in so that others can find it.

Comment: this is what i put `psql -U postgres -h localhost -d projectname`

Comment: Very good. I have typed in an answer with a couple of situations that you ran through. You are welcome to type your own answer and mark your own answer as accepted to put closure to your question. Good work!

Comment: @JustinDing I noticed other questions you have asked but not marked any of the answer as accepted. I'd highly encourage you to consider putting closure to your questions by marking one of the answers as accepted if they have helped you. It's totally optional, but encouraged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What seems to be happening here is that you are asked to access PostgreSQL through SSH tunnel as described here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ssh-tunnels.html

You were asked to use:

```
ssh -L localhost:5432:localhost:5432 -Y ambisense@scifilab.dyndns.org
```

That means, port 5432 from scifilab.dyndns.org will be forwarded to your computer's local port 5432 (as long as your computer's 5432 port is not used by anything else). Once that tunnel is made, you can connect to PostgreSQL on scifilab.dyndns.org as if it was running on your machine.

**Free up port 5432 on your computer**

In your case, 5432 was bound by a local instance of PostgreSQL. `sudo service postgresql stop` or `brew services stop postgresql` or similar command depending on your OS will stop PostgreSQL running locally on your computer and free up port 5432. Once that port is freed up, you can run your ssh command to create a tunnel.

Once the tunnel is made, you can connect to scifilab's PostgreSQL using `psql -h localhost -U youruser -d yourdatabase`.

**Create tunnel to another port instead**

In case you can't get 5432 freed up, you can tunnel scifilab's PostgreSQL to another port on your computer by running:

```
ssh -L localhost:55432:localhost:5432 -Y ambisense@scifilab.dyndns.org
```

Then, you can connect to scifilab's PostgreSQL using:

```
psql -h localhost -p 55432 -U youruser -d yourdatabase
```